# Is there any way to see that $H= p^2 +x^2$ has level-spaced spectrum from the symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I heard that Ken Wilson had an explanation of the level-spacing of the harmonic oscillator spectrum directly from the symmetry of $H$ under interchange of $p$ and $x$, without ladder operators or direct computation.

After some thought, I don't know what such an explanation may be.

Comment: This might be interesting: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/346326/